# Using \hbar from MLModern after loading AMSfonts

Tags: mlmodern

As the title suggests, I am trying to use `\hbar` in conjunction with the `mlmodern` and `amsfonts` packages. I need to use the `\hbar` provided by `mlmodern`, but when `amsfonts` is loaded, I get the original CM/LM.

I have tried the following, which results in an undefined control sequence error for `$\hbar$`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mlmodern}
\let\mlmhbar\hbar

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\let\amshbar\hbar

\begin{document}

\def\hbar{\mlmhbar}

$\hbar$

\end{document}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `\NewCommandCopy`, because `\hbar` is defined as a robust command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mlmodern}
\NewCommandCopy{\mlmhbar}{\hbar}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\NewCommandCopy{\amshbar}{\hbar}% just for the comparison

\RenewCommandCopy{\hbar}{\mlmhbar}

\begin{document}

$h\hbar$ $h\amshbar$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you can see that the bar with MLModern hits the serif of “h”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mlmodern}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\NewCommandCopy{\amshbar}{\hbar}% just for the comparison

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\hbar}{}{%
  {\mathpalette\hbar@bar\relax\mkern -9muh}%
}
\newcommand{\hbar@bar}[2]{\raisebox{-0.075\height}{$\m@th#1\mathchar'26$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$h\hbar$ $h\amshbar$

$\scriptstyle h\hbar$

\end{document}
```

[image]