# Renew qtyrange with default precision value

Tags: siunitx, xparse

i would like to have a default `round-precision` value for `\qtyrange` that is different from the rest of the package, im having some problem changing it

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xparse}
\let\oldqtyrange\qtyrange
\RenewDocumentCommand\qtyrange{
    O{0} % #1 Precision
    o % #2 options
    m % #3 from
    m % #4 to
    m % #5 unit
}{%
    \oldqtyrange[round-precision={#1}, #2]%
    {#3}{#4}{#5}%
}
\begin{document}
\qtyrange[1]{1}{20}{\micro\metre}
\end{document}
```

For some reason the compilation is fixed in a loop.

Comment: Eight years ago, the answer was [Do not do this.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285551) It would be easier to do `\NewDocumentCommand\qtyRange{O{0}O{}mmm}{\qtyrange[round-precision={#1},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5}}`.

Comment: Nowadays, replace `\let` with `\NewCommandCopy`, i.e. `\NewCommandCopy\oldqtyrange\qtyrange`. Closest duplicate I could find: [Q682293](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/682293)

Comment: Oh so the problem was on the second argument! i see, it works now thanks. Also thanks for updating me on that, i just fixed that on my files, i used that so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed by @Qrrbrbirlbel

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\NewCommandCopy\oldqtyrange\qtyrange
\RenewDocumentCommand\qtyrange{
    O{0} % #1 Precision
    O{} % #2 options % <- fixed -----------------------------
    m % #3 from
    m % #4 to
    m % #5 unit
}{%
    \oldqtyrange[round-precision={#1}, #2]%
    {#3}{#4}{#5}%
}
\begin{document}
\qtyrange[1]{1}{20}{\micro\metre}
\end{document}
```